# Php function throws "undefined constant" when using within `array_map`

Tags: php

I am getting a

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ord - assumed 'ord'

On line

```
array_map(ord,str_split($string))
```

Which is surprising since `ord` is a [php function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

And if I were to rewrite the call as:

```
array_map(function ($x) {return ord($x);},str_split($string))
```

The code works without any warning / notices

Any idea why is that ?

Comment: Use `array_map("ord",str_split($string))`

Comment: [Example of using callbacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)

Comment: And the reason this code is actually working (minus the notice) is because an undefined constant gets handled as though it's a quoted string. In the end your `array_map()` function call gets the correct parameters.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much? IMO, its not very intuitive to pass in one thing (string) that gets magically converted into another thing (function) behind-the-scenes - Especially given that an anonymous function works as expected.

Comment: I just got a `popular question` badge for this question, so apparently a lot of people find this `php` behavior confusing (regardless of the 5 downvotes it got for some reason)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Function name should be **[passed](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)** as a ***string*** to a callback parameter.

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo, empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print or unset().

```
array_map("ord",str_split($string))
```

**Edit based on edited question.**

Anonymous functions are *not* name of some other callable functions hence they do not need to be passed as string literals. That requirement is only for passing names of defined callable functions, not anonymous functions.

> Apart from common user-defined function, anonymous functions can also be passed to a callback parameter.

`ord` works fine without quotes within the anonymous function because over there it is not being passed as a callable, it is simply being called on a variable within the body of another function.

Comment: This is not true, if I were to rewrite the call as `array_map(function ($x) {return ord($x);},str_split($string))` it would work without any warning

Comment: It is entirely true. Closures are not function names. See the manual again *Apart from common user-defined function, anonymous functions can also be passed to a callback parameter.* So much so that closures are also called anonymous functions primarily because they don't have a name

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do we know if being able to pass the function name without quotes, like OP tried, is being considered for future versions of PHP? Would it be that hard to do?